# Almost normal subgroups: Is there any notion which is weaker than normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, definition, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group then $N$ a subgroup of $G$ is said to be normal subgroup of $G$ if $\forall g \in G$, $g^{-1}Ng = N$.

Is there any notion which is weaker than normal subgroup? I mean something like almost normal subgroup or nearly normal subgroup in which some of the elements only follow the normality condition.

Comment: Groupprops lists some - https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup#Weaker_properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very important notion is that of **subnormality**: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called subnormal if there is a series $H=H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd  \cdots \lhd H_{n-1} \lhd H_n=G$. Of course every normal subgroup is subnormal, but the converse is not true in general. Helmut Wielandt basically established the theory in 1939, one of his famous results being the [Zipper Lemma](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.849.5859&rep=rep1&type=pdf.).

Other notions to be considered are [*pronormal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronormal_subgroup) subgroups and quasinormal or [*permutable*](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Permutable_subgroup) subgroups, each of which generalizes a certain property of normal subgroups.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the set of all conjugates of a subgroup $H\leq G$, defined by $C=\{gHg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$. If $H$ is normal, clearly $|C|=1$, so $|C|$ can be considered to be  a measure of "how far away from being normal" a subgroup is.

Answer (score 4):

What about $N$ admits only a finite number oof conjugates ? For instance, when the group $G$ acts on a finite space, the stabilizer of a point has this property.

Comment: The second sentence characterizes finite index subgroups.

Answer (score 3):

In the contex of locally compact topological  groups which are equiped with the Haar measure, one can consider the following:
"For almost all $g\in G$ we have $g^{-1} Ng=N$"

In the context of Lie groups, one can consider $g^{-1} N g$ would be isometric to $N$ with metric they inherit from a left (but not right) invariant metric.

In the context of abstract groups one can says "$\cap_g g^{-1} N g$ has finite index in $N$.

Answer (score 2):

$N$ is said to be a commensurated subgroup if $[N:N\cap gNg^{-1}]$ is finite for every $g\in G$. This has many other names (almost normal, $(G,N)$ is a Hecke pair, etc). This notion occurs in various contexts.